# How to Convert Column into Character Type in Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am new to working on Shiny Apps, and relatively new to R in general. In my Shiny App, the data that is uploaded will always have a close_notes column. How can I convert this column into a string before applying the regular expression that I have (and before uppercasing it completely)? My Shiny App is below.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)    # alternatively, this also loads %>%
library(shinyWidgets)


regex_to_apply <- "\\bMASTER DATA\\b|\\bSOURCE LIST\\b|\\bVALIDITY DATES\\b|\\bMRP CONTROLLER\\b|\\bPSV\\b|\\bELIGIBILITY\\b|\\bCOST\\b|\\bMARKETING EXCLUSION\\b|\\bEFFECTIVITY\\b|\\bMISSING\\b|\bbBLANK\\b"

ui <- fluidPage(
    #text with project name and my information
    # use a gradient in background, setting background color to blue
    setBackgroundColor(  
        #https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/setBackgroundColor.html used this website for help on background color
        color = c("#F7FBFF", "#2171B5"),
        gradient = "radial",
        direction = c("top", "left")
    ),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                      accept = c(
                          "text/csv",
                          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                          ".csv")
            ),
            tags$hr(),
            checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
            
            # Button
            downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),
            actionButton('apply_regex', 'Apply Regex')
            
        ),
        mainPanel(
            dataTableOutput("contents")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    rv <- reactiveValues()
    
    observe({
        req(input$file1)
        # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
        # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
        # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
        # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
        # be found.
        inFile <- input$file1
        
        if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)
        
        rv$data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
        
    })
    
    output$contents <- renderDataTable({
        rv$data
    })
    
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("myfile",Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(rv$data, file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$apply_regex, {
        rv$data <- rv$data  %>%filter(grepl(regex_to_apply, toupper(close_notes)))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is  `%>%filter(grepl(regex_to_apply, toupper(as.character(close_notes))))`

Comment: I keep getting this error "Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x invalid multibyte string 54
ℹ Input `..1` is `grepl(regex_to_apply, toupper(as.character(close_notes)))`." any ideas as to why?

Comment: having an extract of your data would help

Comment: i think i found the problem, encoding issue. I'm writing you and answer

Answer (score 0):

What gdevaux recommended worked on my machine. I also got the following to work. You would need to add `library(dplyr)` if you haven't already (I see that you do have that at the top, my bad).

```
observeEvent(input$apply_regex, {
        rv$data <- rv$data %>% 
            mutate(close_notes = close_notes %>% as.character() %>% toupper()) %>% 
            filter(grepl(regex_to_apply, close_notes))
    })
```

Basically just mutate the column before putting it in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing what I said in comment, to transform a column to a string you can use `as.character(your_variable)`.

To me it changed nothing because the problem was and encoding issue. I juste added `encoding = "UTF-8"` when loading the CSV file.

```
rv$data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

You can also add a what @avery robbins suggested, it can save you sometimes when R automatically load strings as factors.